# Write a wrapper function to successfully take addition arguments (like subset) via ellipsis (...)

Tags: r, function, regression, linear-regression, lm

I am writing a function that calls another function (e.g. `lm`), and I would like to pass other 
arguments to it using ellipsis (`...`). However, the data to be used is not
in the global environment, but inside a list. A minimal example:

```
L <-  list(data = chickwts, other = 1:5)

wrapper <-  function(list, formula = NULL, ...){
  if (missing(formula)) formula <-  formula(weight~feed)
  lm(formula, data = list$data, ...)
}

wrapper(L, subset = feed != "casein") #fails
```

I can make it work using `attach` but I'm sure there is more efficient ways of doing it by specifying the evaluation frame...?

```
wrapper2 <-  function(list, formula = NULL, ...){
  if (missing(formula)) formula <-  formula(weight~feed)
  attach(list$data)
  m <- lm(formula, ...)
  detach(list$data)
  return(m)
}

wrapper2(L, subset = feed != "casein") #works
```

Another solution I have used before is to use `list(...)`, and dealing with the arguments manually,  but that would not be practical in the real situation.

I can see that this is fairly basic, but I couldn't find a solution. Any suggestion to the specific problem and also a link to a good conceptual explanation of environments in general would be appreciated.

Comment: The `model.frame` code (which is what `lm` calls in your example) is hideous. Rather than trying to get it to work, I'd suggest just subsetting your data beforehand.

Comment: That's not the point, this is just a minimal example of the real situation (which is more complicated). The problem is the same: how to pass arguments from `...` to a function inside another function without the need of using `attach(list$data)`. Instead of `subset` it can be any arbitrary argument that uses a variable name in the data.

Comment: Ask your real question and not a pretend one.

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear. I asked the real question I just provided a minimal reproducible example. My real problem involves another function in an external package, with several dependencies. I thought that this is not what a good example was. But the programming question is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We would need to construct a `call` and `eval` it.

```
wrapper <-  function(list, formula = NULL, ...){
  if (missing(formula)) formula <- weight ~ feed
  cl <- match.call()
  cl$list <- NULL
  cl$formula <- formula
  cl$data <- quote(list$data)
  cl[[1]] <- quote(stats::lm)
  eval(cl)
  }
```

Reproducible example:

```
L <- list(data = trees, other = 1:5)
wrapper(L, Height ~ Girth, subset = Volume > 20)
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. Is this more efficient than my original solution with `attach`?